# pandas validating data frame cells

Tags: python, regex, validation, pandas

I have a non-indexed data frame (read from a csv file) as follows:

```
John   Mullen  12/08/1993  Passw0rd
Lisa   Bush    06/12/1990  myPass12
Maria  Murphy  30/03/1989  qwErTyUi
Seth   Black   21/06/1991  LoveXmas
```

I would like to validate each cell of each row against a specific **regular expression**:

- validate birth date as `dd/mm/yyyy`
- validate the password with the PassRegex below
- validate First name/ last Name with the NameRegex
- below replace ' in the first name with _
- etc...

and then move the row where any of the cells do not validate to a new data frame.

```
import re
PassRegex = re.compile(r"^(?!.*\s)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d).{8,50}$")
NameRegex = re.compile(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\-]{2,80}$")
```

Is there a way to do this without iterating through the whole data frame row by row, and cell by cell?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please expand your question with a specific use case example, and your current approach to the problem. Even pseudocode is fine, you don't have to make it executable. It will help better understand your question.

Comment: Well for dates you can do `pd.to_datetime(df['date'], coerce=True)` this wil l generate `NaT` where the data format is incorrect and you can use those locations to mask the df and place them in a separate df

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do this without iterating through the whole data
>   frame row by row, and cell by cell?

You don't have to look at every value in every row, but clearly, in every row, you have to look at the columns relevant to your filter/conditional.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from dateutil.parser import parse

df = DataFrame([['John', 'Mullen', '12/08/1993',  'Passw0rd'],
... ['Lisa',   'Bush' ,   '06/12/1990',  'myPass12'],
... ['Maria' , 'Murphy',  '30/03/1989',  'qwErTyUi'],
... ['Seth' ,  'Black' ,  '21/06/1991' , 'LoveXmas']])

df.columns = ['name1','name2','date','pwd']

# convert date column to datetime type
df.date = df.date.apply(parse)

>>> df[df.date > parse('1/1/91')]
  name1   name2       date       pwd
0  John  Mullen 1993-12-08  Passw0rd
3  Seth   Black 1991-06-21  LoveXmas

>>> df[df.date <= parse('1/1/91')]
   name1   name2       date       pwd
1   Lisa    Bush 1990-06-12  myPass12
2  Maria  Murphy 1989-03-30  qwErTyUi

>> indexes = df[df.date <= parse('1/1/91')].index
>> new_df = DataFrame(df.drop(indexes))
>>> new_df
  name1   name2       date       pwd
0  John  Mullen 1993-12-08  Passw0rd
3  Seth   Black 1991-06-21  LoveXmas
```